# Validação via Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Na minha aplicação que gerencia **Cursos**, estou precisando de uma validação via `javascript`. Tenho uma tela onde o **aluno** faz sua inscrição em um determinado curso, o que eu queria é que quando ele clicar no botão **inscrição** aparecesse a mensagem **Inscrição efetuada com sucesso**, e a outra é quando ele tentar se inscrever **no mesmo** curso, nesse casa deve aparecer a mensagem **Você já está inscrito nesse curso**. Tentei fazer da forma abaixo na `function Alerta` mas minha mensagem só cai no `else`. Alguém pode me ajudar?

**Minha View**

```html
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.Curso>

<h2>Catálogo de Cursos</h2>

<span class="pull-right">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Inscricao", "Curso", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p>
            Pesquisar Curso: @Html.TextBox("pesquisar")
            <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </p>
    }
</span>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Curso
        </th>
        <th>
            Sigla
        </th>
        <th>
            Ementa
        </th>
        <th>
            Inicio
        </th>
        <th>
            Fim
        </th>
        <th>
            Carga Horária
        </th>
        <th>
            Turno
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantidade de Vagas
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
           <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome_Curso)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sigla)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="~/Curso/Ementa?id=@item.Id">Ementa</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dt_Inicio)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dt_Fim)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Carga_Horaria)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Turno)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qtd_Vagas)
            </td>
            <td>

                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Inscricao", "Curso", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            if (item.Qtd_Vagas > 0)
                             {
                                 <a class="inscricao btn btn-success" onclick="$(this).parents('form').submit(), Alerta()">Inscrição</a>
                                 <input type="hidden" value="@item.Id" name="inscricaoId" />
                             }
                            else
                            {
                                 <input type="submit" value="Não há vagas" name="detalhes" class="inscricao btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"/>
                            }
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    }

</table>
<div class="form-group">

    <a href="@Url.Action("HomeAluno", "Home")"><input type="button" value="Voltar" class="btn btn-danger" /></a>

</div>
<br />


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".inscricao").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Inscricao/",
                    data: { inscricaoId: $(this).data("inscricaoid") },
                    success: function() {
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
      <--! TENTEI FAZER ASSIM, MAS SÓ ME APARECE A MENSAGEM DO ELSE -->
        function Alerta() {

            if (document.getElementsByClassName("inscricao").value == null) {
                alert("Cadastro realizado com Sucesso!");
            } else {
                alert("Você já está inscrito nesse Curso!");
            }
        }
    </script>

}
```

**Minha Action Inscricao**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Inscricao(int inscricaoId, string pesquisar)
    {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            //Aqui pega o usuario logado
            Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
            if (aluno == null)
                return View("MeusCursos");

            //Aqui pega o curso selecionado
            var curso = db.Cursos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == inscricaoId);
            if (curso == null)
                return View("MeusCursos");

            //Aqui verifica se o aluno já está inscrito em algum curso
            var alunoCurso = db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.Curso.Id == inscricaoId && ac.Aluno.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
            if (alunoCurso != null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Inscricao", "Curso");
            }

            //Aqui faz a associação do Aluno e Curso
            alunoCurso = new AlunoCurso
            {
                Aluno = aluno,
                Curso = curso
            };

            db.AlunoCursos.Add(alunoCurso);
            db.SaveChanges();

            //Aqui decrementa a quantidade de vagas dos Cursos
            curso.Qtd_Vagas--;
            db.Entry(curso).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            scope.Complete();
        }

        var cursos = from c in db.Cursos select c;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pesquisar))
        {
            cursos = cursos.Where(c => c.Nome_Curso.Contains(pesquisar));
        }
        cursos = cursos.OrderBy(a => a.Nome_Curso);

        return View(cursos.ToList());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

É possivel utilizar a função success para resolver os dois problemas, na Action "Inscrição" você deve manter o código atual, adicionando apenas uma validação para conferir se o usuário já está cadastrado para aquele curso, caso ele não esteja cadastre-o como estava fazendo antes e retorne um objeto JSON no final alertando que o cadastro foi realizado.

Na parte da Action o que vai mudar é o retorno, como é um cadastro via AJAX antes você não retornava nada, mas é possível retornar um objeto JSON, definindo um atributo de sua escolha e o valor do mesmo, tal objeto pode ser consultado na function success do AJAX, realizando a lógica necessária baseando-se nele.

Para resolver o seu problema retornaremos um atributo chamado 'success', se o valor for 'true' o usuário foi cadastrado, se for 'false' é porque já está cadastrado no devido curso, segue exemplo:

**Retorno Json na Action**

```
public ActionResult Inscricao(/*seus parametros*/ ){
/*coloque aqui o código para enviar a view de inscrição com seus parametros*/
    return View();
}



//essa Action deve ser usada somente por Ajax para conferir o cadastro
[Http.Post]
public ActionResult Inscreve(int InscricaoID){
    if(/* crie um código para validar se já está no curso*/){
          return Json( new {success = "false"});
    }
    else{
       /* coloque aqui o seu código atual de cadastro */
         return Json( new {success = "true"});
    }    
}
```

**Código javascritp do ajax**

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".inscricao").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("Inscreve")",
                    data: { inscricaoId: $(this).data("inscricaoid") },
                    success: function(objetoJson) {
                        if(objetoJson.success == true)
                           alert('O cadastro foi realizado com sucesso!');
                        else
                           alert('Você já está inscrito nesse Curso');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Portanto trabalhando com objetos json na reposta da Action e analisando essas repostas na função success do AJAX você pode resolver esse seu problema.

Comment: Esses retornos vem em `Popup` @FernandoMedeiros?

Comment: o retorno vai vir encapsulado em um objeto Json, esse objeto pode ser manipulado se colocado como parametro da function success, no caso o que cria o popup é a função "alert()" do javascript

Comment: Aquele Retorno Json eu coloco na minha **Action**?

Comment: Não teria uma forma de fazer isso com o `javascript` não @FernandoMedeiros, com **Json** tive problemas.

Comment: Confira a edição que fiz na resposta, agora deve funcionar com o JSON

Comment: Coloquei minha **Action** na pergunta @FernandoMedeiros.

Comment: Amigo, por se tratar de uma Action utilizada por AJAX, não tem porque você retornar uma View, a View representa HTML a ser enviado para representação do browser, no seu caso pelo o que parece só é necessária a sinalização de se o usuario foi cadastrado ou não, então troque os retornos da View por retorno de Json atendendo ao que usei no meu exemplo

Comment: Caso minha reposta tenha sido util por favor avalie-a, obrigado

Comment: Preciso só de um simples alert `javascript`

Comment: É o que está implementado no meu exemplo, faça o que eu disse, retorne o JSON ao invés da View, caso voce use essa action para outros fins, crie uma nova Action para fazer essa parte de cadastro do usuario, neste caso seria necessário mudar o caminho da URL no AJAX

Comment: Justamente, eu teria que fazer mais alterações na minha action e teria que criar outra. A mensagem que o Json está me retornando é essa `{"sucess":"false"}` me redirecionando para uma pagina só com essa mensagem, e não um `Popup`.

Comment: Cria uma Action exclusiva para o cadastro do usuario, você está fazendo mal uso do design MVC, crie uma Action para cada função, está retornando esse JSON porque voce usa essa mesma Action para retornar a View do formulario

Comment: Verifique minha alteração na resposta.

Comment: Nessa minha **action** eu não faço nenhum cadastro de usuário. Só faço uma coisa que é: Nessa minha action tem uma lista de **cursos** e um botão **inscrição** mas é inscrição de curso, o **aluno** já cadastrado no sistema só clica no botão e deveria aparecer as mensagens: **Inscrição efetuada com sucesso.** e caso ele tente se inscrever no mesmo curso novamente **Você já está inscrito nesse curso**.

Answer (score 1):

Vi a duvida nos comentários acima e resolvi reforçar o dito pelo nosso amigo @Fernando Medeiros no seu próprio código!

na sua tag script no seu success você vai fazer a seguinte alteração:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".inscricao").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Inscricao/",
                data: { inscricaoId: $(this).data("inscricaoid") },
                success: function(data) {
                     /*se o seu retorno dentro do JSON for true quer dizer que está tudo OK! então será efetuado o redirect! Certo ?*/
                     if(data == true) {
                         alert("usuario cadastrado com sucesso :D");
                         window.location.reload();
                     }
                     /*Já se o mesmo vier como falso ele não entrá no if será exibido o alerta para seu usuário!*/
                     alert("você já está inscrito nesse curso")
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Agora vamos para alteração na sua action ..

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Inscricao(int inscricaoId, string pesquisar)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        //Aqui pega o usuario logado
        Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
        if (aluno == null)
            return View("MeusCursos");

        //Aqui pega o curso selecionado
        var curso = db.Cursos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == inscricaoId);
        if (curso == null)
            return View("MeusCursos");

        //Aqui verifica se o aluno já está inscrito em algum curso
        var alunoCurso = db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.Curso.Id == inscricaoId && ac.Aluno.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
        if (alunoCurso != null)
        {
            /*Aqui vamos retornar o JSON para seu javascript mostrar o alert fora do if vamos retornar um false para o mesmo*/
            return new JsonResult() { Data = false, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }

        //Aqui faz a associação do Aluno e Curso
        alunoCurso = new AlunoCurso
        {
            Aluno = aluno,
            Curso = curso
        };

        db.AlunoCursos.Add(alunoCurso);
        db.SaveChanges();

        //Aqui decrementa a quantidade de vagas dos Cursos
        curso.Qtd_Vagas--;
        db.Entry(curso).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        scope.Complete();
    }

    /*E para finalizar ao invés de retonar uma nova view para seu ajax vocÊ vai retornar um json confirmando que o mesmo foi salvo com sucesso, sua aplicação mostrará o alert e depois recarregara sua pagina*/
    /*Vale também lembrar que no data onde retorno false pode ser retornado varias outras informações como um objeto ou string .. que pode ser tratada pelo seu javascript :D*/
    return new JsonResult() { Data = true, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };

}
```

OBS: A implementação é a mesma de nosso amigo @Fernando Medeiros

Espero ter ajudado :D